# trying to connect GLUE to Snowflake to write a json file on S3 to a table on snowflake

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o108.pyWriteDynamicFrame.
: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 44 unexpected ')'.

Using Glue Studio tried to connect to snowflake to create a table with source from s3 json file.  I keep getting this "unexpected ')'"error.  Could it be a bug in GLUE Studio on how it's sending compiled sql to snowflake? or is it something on Snowflake, I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

"unexpected" error is typically a syntax error in the SQL query that was sent to Snowflake. Try running the same SQL query directly in Snowflake to see if you get the same error. If you can't reproduce this in SF console it's most probably a bug in GS.